# TypeError creating custom Block Type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to create a custom Block and I want to use RichText.

I do (I have shortened the code). But find any sample using RichText and it fails for me:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { RichText, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

...

edit: (attributes, setAttributes) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();

        return (
          <div>
              Richtext:
              <RichText />
          </div>
        );
    },
```

The error I am seeing in console is:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useBlockProps')

I have also run / installed the packages or what they are called.
npm install @wordpress/editor -save
npm install @wordpress/block-editor -save
npm @wordpress/components -save